# RDLC report issue for multiple columns

Tags: c#, sql, rdlc, subreport

please check below tables.

Table1

```
Key    Title     Type
----------------------
A1     Test1       A 
A2     Test2       A 
B1     Test1       B
B2     Test2       B
B3     Test3       B
C1     Test1       C
C2     Test2       C
```

Table2

```
Id   Name    Address      A        B            C 
---------------------------------------------------
 1   Soham   Add1         A1       B1,B3        C2
 2   Varun   Add2         A1,A2    B1,B2,B4     C1
```

My rdlc report will look like  for Id = 1

```
Name : Soham
Address : Add1
Type : A
         A1  - Yes
         A2  - No

Type : B 
         B1 -  Yes
         B2 -  No
         B3 -  Yes
         B4 -  No

Type : C
         C1 -  No
         C2 -  Yes
```

and for report will look like  for Id = 2

```
Name : Varun
Address : Add2
Type : A
         A1  - Yes
         A2  - Yes

Type : B 
         B1 -  Yes
         B2 -  Yes
         B3 -  No
         B4 -  Yes

Type : C
         C1 -  Yes
         C2 -  No
```

How could I achieve in single query if I am not using Sub report.
Or how can I achieve this using Sub Report

Comment: Which SQL... MySQL, SQL-Server ???

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL, then you can use the "FIND_IN_SET()" function and apply like this... It will return ONE result set in correct sequence for your RDLC via simple data grouping...

```
select
      PreQuery.*
   from
      ( select
              t2.id,
              t2.`name`,
              t2.Address,
              t1.`type`,
              t1.`key`,
              case when FIND_IN_SET(t1.`key`, t2.A )  > 0 then 'yes' else 'no ' end HasKey
           from
              table1 t1,
              table2 t2
           where
              t1.`type` = 'A'
        UNION    
        select
              t2.id,
              t2.`name`,
              t2.Address,
              t1.`type`,
              t1.`key`,
              case when FIND_IN_SET(t1.`key`, t2.B )  > 0 then 'yes' else 'no ' end HasKey
           from
              table1 t1,
              table2 t2
           where
              t1.`type` = 'B'
        UNION    
        select
              t2.id,
              t2.`name`,
              t2.Address,
              t1.`type`,
              t1.`key`,
              case when FIND_IN_SET(t1.`key`, t2.C )  > 0 then 'yes' else 'no ' end HasKey
           from
              table1 t1,
              table2 t2
           where
              t1.`type` = 'C' ) PreQuery
   order by
      PreQuery.`name`,
      PreQuery.`type`,
      PreQuery.`key`
```

If you are using SQL-Server, change the function call from FIND_IN_SET() to CHARINDEX()

Now, even though the above query will get you what you want, what you have is really bad database design.  You should actually have another table with the user's key and what they have... such as...

```
UserHasTable
userHasID   int auto-increment
userid      int           <-- to link to the person
hasKey      varchar(??)   <-- to correspond with the 'key' they have.
```

Then, the records would be for each person would be something like

```
UserHasID   UserID  HasKey
1           1       A1
2           1       B1
3           1       B3
4           1       C2
5           2       A1
6           2       A2
7           2       B1
8           2       B2
9           2       B4
10          2       C1
```

Then, your query could be simplified without having to explicitly break up each A, B, C column